# RabbitMQ logins via LDAP failing

Tags: active-directory, ldap, rabbitmq

We are currently running RabbitMQ 3.5.6, and though it is able to successfully bind to the LDAP server, logins to the management UI via LDAP credentials are failing. I've been unable to track down the cause of this.

Our end goal is to have users be able to log into the RabbitMQ management UI with their LDAP credentials, and have RabbitMQ assign them permissions based on the groups that they are a member of in LDAP.

Upon login, both with a local account that I created for testing purposes and with my LDAP credentials I am presented with an internal server error:

```
Got response code 500 with body {"error":"Internal Server Error","reason":"{error,\n {try_clause,\n [{\"CN=rabbit,OU=System,OU=People,DC=domain,DC=tld\",\n \"LDAP_PASSWORD\"}]},\n [{rabbit_auth_backend_ldap,with_ldap,3,\n [{file,\"rabbitmq-auth-backend-ldap/src/rabbit_auth_backend_ldap.erl\"},\n {line,271}]},\n {rabbit_auth_backend_ldap,user_login_authentication,2,\n [{file,\"rabbitmq-auth-backend-ldap/src/rabbit_auth_backend_ldap.erl\"},\n {line,59}]},\n {rabbit_access_control,try_authenticate,3,\n [{file,\"src/rabbit_access_control.erl\"},{line,91}]},\n {rabbit_access_control,'-check_user_login/2-fun-0-',4,\n [{file,\"src/rabbit_access_control.erl\"},{line,77}]},\n {lists,foldl,3,[{file,\"lists.erl\"},{line,1262}]},\n {rabbit_mgmt_util,is_authorized,6,\n [{file,\"rabbitmq-management/src/rabbit_mgmt_util.erl\"},{line,121}]},\n {webmachine_resource,resource_call,3,\n [{file,\n \"webmachine-wrapper/webmachine-git/src/webmachine_resource.erl\"},\n {line,186}]},\n {webmachine_resource,do,3,\n [{file,\n \"webmachine-wrapper/webmachine-git/src/webmachine_resource.erl\"},\n {line,142}]}]}\n"}
```

The `rabbitmq.config` that I am currently using is below, followed by the log entries generated by RabbitMQ.

---

```
%% -*- mode: erlang -*-
[
    {rabbit,
        [{tcp_listeners, []},
        {ssl_listeners, [{"10.7.232.1", 5672}]},
        {log_levels, [{connection, info}, {channel, info}]},
        {reverse_dns_lookups, true},
        {ssl_options, [{certfile, "/usr/local/etc/rabbitmq/rmqs01.cer"},
            {keyfile, "/usr/local/etc/rabbitmq/rmqs01.key"}]},
        {auth_backends, [rabbit_auth_backend_ldap, rabbit_auth_backend_internal]},
        {auth_mechanisms, ['PLAIN']}
    ]},

    {rabbitmq_auth_backend_ldap,
        [{servers, ["dc01.domain.tld", "dc02.domain.tld", "dc03.domain.tld"]},
        %%{user_dn_pattern, "cn=${username},ou=People,dc=domain,dc=tld"},
    {user_dn_pattern, []},
        {use_starttls, true},
    %% necessary for our ldap setup
    {dn_lookup_attribute, "sAMAccountName"},
    {dn_lookup_base, "OU=People,DC=domain,DC=tld"},
        {dn_lookup_bind, [{"CN=rabbit,OU=System,OU=People,DC=domain,DC=tld", "rmqpassword"}]},
        {port, 389},
        {timeout, 30000},
        {other_bind, [{"CN=rabbit,OU=System,OU=People,DC=domain,DC=tld", "rmqpassword"}]},
        {log, network},
    %% ACL testing
    {resource_access_query,
     {for, [{resource, exchange,
        {for, [{permission, configure,
        { in_group, "OU=Systems,OU=People,DC=domain,DC=tld" } },
        {permission, write, {constant, true}},
        {permission, read,  {constant, true}}
        ]}},
    {resource, queue, {constant, true}} ]}}
    ]},

    {rabbitmq_management,
        %%{http_log_dir, "/var/log/rabbitmq/access.log"},
        [{listener,
            [{port, 15672},
                {ip, "10.7.232.1"},
                {ssl, true},
                {ssl_opts,
                [{certfile, "/usr/local/etc/rabbitmq/rmqs01.cer"},
                    {keyfile, "/usr/local/etc/rabbitmq/rmqs01.key"}
                ]}
            ]}
        ]}
].
```

---

```
=INFO REPORT==== 10-May-2016::10:17:47 ===
LDAP CHECK: login for username

=INFO REPORT==== 10-May-2016::10:17:47 ===
    LDAP connecting to servers: ["dc01.domain.tld",
                                 "dc02.domain.tld",
                                 "dc03.domain.tld"]

=ERROR REPORT==== 10-May-2016::10:17:47 ===
webmachine error: path="/api/whoami"
{error,
    {try_clause,
        [{"CN=rabbit,OU=System,OU=People,DC=domain,DC=tld",
          "rmqpassword"}]},
    [{rabbit_auth_backend_ldap,with_ldap,3,
         [{file,"rabbitmq-auth-backend-ldap/src/rabbit_auth_backend_ldap.erl"},
          {line,271}]},
     {rabbit_auth_backend_ldap,user_login_authentication,2,
         [{file,"rabbitmq-auth-backend-ldap/src/rabbit_auth_backend_ldap.erl"},
          {line,59}]},
     {rabbit_access_control,try_authenticate,3,
         [{file,"src/rabbit_access_control.erl"},{line,91}]},
     {rabbit_access_control,'-check_user_login/2-fun-0-',4,
         [{file,"src/rabbit_access_control.erl"},{line,77}]},
     {lists,foldl,3,[{file,"lists.erl"},{line,1262}]},
     {rabbit_mgmt_util,is_authorized,6,
         [{file,"rabbitmq-management/src/rabbit_mgmt_util.erl"},{line,121}]},
     {webmachine_resource,resource_call,3,
         [{file,
              "webmachine-wrapper/webmachine-git/src/webmachine_resource.erl"},
          {line,186}]},
     {webmachine_resource,do,3,
         [{file,
              "webmachine-wrapper/webmachine-git/src/webmachine_resource.erl"},
          {line,142}]}]}
```

Comment: Turns out `{dn_lookup_bind, [{"CN=rabbit,OU=System,OU=People,DC=domain,DC=tld", "rmqpassword"}]}` needed to be `{dn_lookup_bind, {"CN=rabbit,OU=System,OU=People,DC=domain,DC=tld", "rmqpassword"}}`.